# Automatic video merger

Tags: javascript, video, merge, video-processing

Every week for my job, I am given a list of links of videos and have to download them, edit them, and then compile them into a single video. Compiling these videos is easy, but it is super tedious and takes around three hours to make them. I would like to know if there are any programs that could automate this. If not, I would like to write something that would.

I sort of know Java, but am no expert. I think that Javascript would be best for this (I KNOW THAT THEY ARE NOT THE SAME). BUT I have a ton of time and can learn whatever I need to, but I just need to know what I need to learn.

What I need it to be able to do is:

-Be given a list of links that go directly to a video in a webplayer

-download those links to a specific folder

-merge those videos together

-render and download the final video

Any help to make a single part of this or direction in general would be awesome!

Comment:  This is an “I want a pony” question which makes it too broad and outside the focus of Stack Overflow. If you can make an attempt and then show us your code we can understand what you’re trying to do on a technical level. Even a small amount of code, however incomplete, can give us context and illustrate your intentions. If you really don't know where to start and need guidance or support consider mentoring and coaching services like [Codementor](https://www.codementor.io), [Savvy](https://www.savvy.is), or [airpair](https://www.airpair.com).

Comment: I would take a look at ffmpeg and using a shell/powershell script to control it. It (or something like cURL) can handle the downloads, and ffmpeg can then be used to trim (if needed) and concatenate the clips